# is there possible to use a cloudflered tunnel to run a web app on internet instead of using a ip public from a SPI?

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

I make an web app and I have my own server I want to have the app in production but I do not want now to by a ip public sevice, I make a cloudflared tunnel but it is only working in my local web, I do know how to make the app on internet by the cloudflared tunnel.

Is there any any body that can help me please

I want to find the answer for the issue,if someone resolve this domain issue